# Loading certificates into ssl with certs store, not file path; with python

Tags: python, windows, ssl

I am using the `ssl` module in python, specifically this:

[SSLContext.load_cert_chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.load_cert_chain)

Most examples of using this show using file paths as the first two parameters like this:

`context.load_cert_chain("/path/to/cert.pem", "/path/to/key.pem", password=password)`

What if these certificates are stored in the Windows certs store? (CA, Root, etc).  Can I still retrieve and then use the file path to pass into the above method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: It doesn't work easily.

The `ssl` module offers some access to the Windows certificate store via `ssl.enum_certificates` but that is pretty limited and does not offer access to the private key (which might even be marked as not-exportable).

The Windows certificate store is automatically used for client connections, to verify the servers certificate. But you cannot easily use it to create a server side context.

If you want to store keys and certificates in the Windows certificate store, you need to use the Windows SSPI (SChannel) APIs to implement the TLS layer. The python `ssl` module doesn't help in that case. The SSPI provides an API similar to the `ssl.SSLObject` which wraps the OpenSSL MemoryBIO protocol, so in theory one could implement a `ssl.SSLObject` on top of the Win32 APIs instead of the Openssl APIs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthn/creating-a-secure-connection-using-schannel